# How to remove the section label boxes surrounding the section label in pie chart

Tags: java, jfreechart

Is it possible to remove the section label boxes from the below pie chart.I searched alot but was not able to get an answer.

![enter image description here]
[1] http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2vkhuyp&s=5

the above link is for pie chart drawn using java.I mean i dont want the percent shown inside the pie chart surrounded with a box it should just show the percent for ex.14%

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=116790) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
    PiePlot plot = (PiePlot) chart.getPlot();
    plot.setLabelBackgroundPaint(null);
    plot.setLabelOutlinePaint(null);
    plot.setLabelShadowPaint(null);
```